# how to make the elements of a form interact in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I develop a form in angular, and I wish that when I choose an element in my select, a value appears in my input. Also, given that the values ​​that I get in my select come from a server, I would like to display a label corresponding to these values, for example: if I recover "AL" I would like to display front "ALLAN".

I work on three files

A.component.html:

```
<form [formGroup]="action" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

     // When I get back the type I'd like to display a different value than the one I'm looking for while keeping the base value in .ts
     <div class="form-group">
         <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Type</label>
         <select formControlName="type" class="form-control" *ngFor="let i of Type">
             <option *ngIf="{{i.type}}==ab" >{{tab2.label}}</option>
         </select>
      </div>

      // I would like to change this value when the type is chosen
      <div class="form-group" *ngFor="let t of Type">
         <label for="name" class="col-form-label">Nom:</label>
         <input type="text" formControlName="libelle" class="form-control" *ngIf="{{t.type}}==ab" value="{{tab.label}}" readonly="readonly">
      </div>
      <div class="footer">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary (click)="onSubmit()">Enregistrer</button>
      </div>

</form>
```

A.component.ts:

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation,} from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Environnement } from 'src/app/models';
import { AdministrationService } from 'src/app/services';
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Name, Type } from 'src/app/app.constants';


@Component({
    selector: 'o-liaisonA',
    templateUrl: './A.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./A.component.less'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class AComponent implements OnInit {

    //var 
    Type: Environnement[];

    // Formulaire
    action: FormGroup;
    type: FormControl;
    libelle: FormControl;
    tab = Name;
    tab2 = Type;

    // Constructor
    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private administrationService: AdministrationService) {
        super();
        this.buildForm();
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getType();
    }

    getFormGroup(): FormGroup {
        return this.action;
    }

    private buildForm() {
        this.submitted = false;

        this.type = this.fb.control('', Validators.required);
        this.libelle = this.fb.control('', Validators.required);

        this.action = this.fb.group({
            type: this.type,
            libelle: this.libelle
        });
    }

    getType(): void {
        this.administrationService.getType()
            .subscribe(
                (Type) => {
                    this.Type = Type;
                    console.log(Type);
                }
            );
    }
```

app.constants.ts:

```
export const Name = [
    {
        label: 'abibi',
        name: 'ab'
    },
    {
        label: 'cdidi',
        type: 'cd'
    }
];

export const Type = [
    {
        label: 'Rest',
        name: 'ab'
    },
    {
        label: 'Api',
        name: 'cd'
    }
]
```

for info my service returns to me:

```
{
  "type": [
    "ab", 
    "cd", 
    "ef"
  ]
}
```

It does not work as expected, 
I have errors

Comment: Please add the error messages to your question .

Comment: I removed the "{ }", there is no error but it still does not work

Comment: You seem to be overcomplicating this.  Bind the attribute to the form field and to the selection.  It really is as easy as that.  It no longer matters if you change it from the view or from the controller code.

Comment: I think you did not understand my problem, it should not be the same value,  but rather that when I choose a value in my select, a value is displayed in my input

Answer (score 2):

Change this

```
<option *ngIf="{{i.type}}==ab" >{{tab2.label}}</option>
```

to

```
<option *ngIf="i.type==ab" >{{tab2.label}}</option>
```

Also change

```
<input *ngIf={{t.type}}==ab" type="text" formControlName="libelle" class="form-control"  value="{{tab.label}}" readonly="readonly" />
```

to

```
<input type="text" formControlName="libelle" class="form-control" *ngIf="t.type==ab" readonly="readonly">
```

Modified response

```
<form [formGroup]="action" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Type</label>
        <select formControlName="type" class="form-control"  (change)="onChange($event.target.value)">
            <option *ngFor="let i of Type">{{i}}</option>
        </select>
     </div>
    <input type="text" formControlName="libelle" class="form-control"  readonly="readonly" /> 
     <div class="footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onSubmit()">Enregistrer</button>
     </div>   
</form>
```

Add this in .ts file

```
onChange(value){
    this.action.get('libelle').setValue(value)
}
```

Also for " if I recover "AL" I would like to display front "ALLAN"."

This should be returned from server API as a array of objects as key value pair

```
 [
    { "label": "Allan", "value": "ab"},
    { "label": "Sam", "value": "cd"},
    { "label": "John", "value": "ef"}
 ]
```

And modify option tag as below

```
<option *ngFor="let i of Type" [value]="i.value">{{i.label}}</option>
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: tab.label does not display anything

Comment: Please try the modified response

Comment: thank you the label display works but the libelle  does not work

Comment: @Cedric Tegue: So you are not getting libelle displayed in input box and have you added change handler in Select (change)="onChange($event.target.value)" as well as added onChange function in .ts file as suggested in post...

Comment: @CedricTegue: So changing values in Select leaves input blank or it display something like "ab" "cd" "ef"

Comment: input displays tab.label and when i change the value of select nothing changes

Comment: @CedricTegue: Can try removing value="tab.label" from input <input formControlName="libelle" type="text" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" />

Comment: Anyway, thank you for your time, do you know how to make an input invisible?

Comment: @CedricTegue: By making type="hidden"